# Тестируем класс

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты

У меня есть простенький класс на основе которого, хочу попробовать написать свой первый тест. На данный момент я двигаюсь по следующей схеме, создал в (androidTest) класс `StringFormaterTest`, в котором собственно так и понимаю нужно писать, и писать по логике set/when/then. Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно реализовать.

```
public class StringFormater {
    Context context;
public StringFormater(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public String formatString(String str, int resId) {
    return String.format("%s %s", context.getResources().getString(resId), str);
    }
}
```

Comment: для Вашего класса нужно создавать в (test) так как (androidTest) - это для UI тестов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё раз сначала
Если у Вас простенький метод, без использования эмулятора, тогда вам в папку test. Если же Вы всё же задействуете UI и вообще эмулятор android, тогда Вам в (androidTest) сохранять тестовые классы.
Далее необходимо компилировать следующие компоненты приложения:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
```

После чего уже можно делать какие то простенькие тесты:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class StringFormatterTest {
    private Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

@Test
public void testFormatString() {
    StringFormatter stringFormatter = new StringFormatter(targetContext);

    assertEquals("Name: name", stringFormatter.formatString(null, R.string.name));
    assertEquals("Username: Username", stringFormatter.formatString("Username", R.string.creator));
    }
}
```

Где заменяем Ваш context на targetContext и инициализируем его следующим образом. Также посоветовал бы дополнительно добавить в  `build.gradle`:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
```

Ожидаемые значения вводите уже сами в `assertEquals`, из Вашего кода я так понял Вы прибавляете к одной строке другую. Поэтому ориентировочно дал значения. 
После того как подготовите значения под себя, запускайтесь через "Edit configurations". Там Вы должны будете выбрать "Android Tests", после чего в самой конфигурации прописать поле Name - любое; Module - app; Specific instrumentation runner - android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner ну и собственно Ok.
У Вас запуститься эммулятор/ну или если Вы тестируете на реальных устройствах, то на нём. А ниже в логах, будет показано прошли ли Ваши тесты, если да то сколько. После чего Вы либо меняете метод, написанный Вами ранее(что скорей всего), или же подгоняете(не советую это делать) Ваши тесты.